# sending live data reading from raspberry pi to internet

Tags: raspbian

i m using raspberry pi model B and interface it with rdm6300 rfid reader . i want to send my data on internet where i can read my rfid card number on internet and want to display on desire position

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a script (python , perl , C ,etc) to interact with the rfid reader and to send the data to "Xively" or "Google Spreadsheet", etc. 
(There is this module called "gspread" for Google Spreadsheet on github.)
(And If you are to use online storages that will return in JSON object or java-script format , Freeboard is very useful for displaying purposes.)
I found "Node-Red" very useful for prototyping.

Answer (score 0):

There's several ways you can do this, I've found [Xively](https://xively.com/dev/tutorials/pi/) to be pretty easy to setup.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide a link for reference.